# json_normalize for nested ordereddict

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

i try to convert nested ordereddict using json_normalize.
however for the nested ordereddict, it only manage to define header but put the values as NaN.
below is the sample data for ordered dict

```
data = [OrderedDict([('name', 'HTTP'),
              ('or',
               OrderedDict([('name', '1'),
                            ('ip-port-tcp',
                             ['10001',
                              '9001'])]))]),
 OrderedDict([('name', 'L3045_1'),
              ('and',
               OrderedDict([('name', '1'),
                            ('or',
                             [OrderedDict([('name', '1'),
                                           ('ip-address',
                                            ['123.3.208.1',
                                             '122.255.199.2'])]),
                              OrderedDict([('name', '2'),
                                           ('ip-port-tcp',
                                            ['443', '80'])])])]))]),
 OrderedDict([('name', 'L3045_2'),
              ('and',
               OrderedDict([('name', '1'),
                            ('ip-port-tcp', '443'),
                            ('or',
                             OrderedDict([('name', '1'),
                                          ('ip-address',
                                           ['121.98.27.10',
                                            '10.241.58.30'])]))]))])
]
```

i get the output as below
[image: output of json normalize]

as we can see in the above, the json_normalize can define the header in nested ordereddict as and.or.xxx however, the value is all store in and.or, where the expected output it should align between the header and the value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how complex your data can be and I'm not sure a dataframe is the best way to represent what seems to be a logical combination of firewall rules.
Anyway, for this specific column, you can first `explode` it to get new rows, then `json_normalize` the exploded column and finally `update` and `join` your original df with the renamed columns:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data)

df = df.explode('and.or').reset_index(drop=True)
df_and_or = pd.json_normalize(df['and.or'])
df_and_or.columns = 'and.or.' + df_and_or.columns

df.update(df_and_or)
df = df.join(df_and_or[df_and_or.columns.difference(df.columns)])
print(df.drop('and.or', axis=1))
```

Output:

```
      name or.name or.ip-port-tcp and.name and.ip-port-tcp and.or.name             and.or.ip-address and.or.ip-port-tcp
0     HTTP       1  [10001, 9001]      NaN             NaN         NaN                           NaN                NaN
1  L3045_1     NaN            NaN        1             NaN           1  [123.3.208.1, 122.255.199.2]                NaN
2  L3045_1     NaN            NaN        1             NaN           2                           NaN          [443, 80]
3  L3045_2     NaN            NaN        1             443           1  [121.98.27.10, 10.241.58.30]                NaN
```

Edit: adding new columns to final result

Comment: thanks for the response, unfortunately i get error 'column must be unique' when running the explode.

Comment: Does your data differ from the question? If so please update it. Otherwise please provide debug information (your exact code with error message). What pandas version do you run?

Comment: hi Tranbi, my mistake, i put wrong data.
this time i put correct data as the question, however i get error "'float' object has no attribute 'values'" in json_normalize.

any clue for this? i try to use dropna in json_normalize. it working however the mapping were incorrect.

Comment: I can't help you without anymore detail. Double check your data and the code you're running to see if they match your question / my answer. If the problem persists provide full code and Error message.